# Is it possible to have 2 instance variables with the same name in Ruby on Rail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have an authentication system set up.
My application_controller.rb has this:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

I am using a tutorial to create a reset password option and it says to add this to my application_controller.rb:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
end
```

Is it possible for me to combine these?

Comment: No, not in the same namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you want to code to do, it's hard to give a concrete answer, but here's something you can do to accept both:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  @current_user ||= User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
end
```

This will set priority to your session[:user_id], but if you want it to be the other way around, just reverse the order of the two lines.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, it is perfectly fine to have **instance variables** of the same name in a controller.

For example

```
#users_controller.rb

def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
  #other code
end
```

As you can see, both are able to use the instance variable of `@user` in the same controller.

The problem you are facing now actually isn't about using the same instance variables, but having the same `method names` within your `application_controller`.

In other words you cannot do

```
def new_method
 #do something
end

def new_method
 #do something else
end
```

Comment: You can absolutely do that. The second `new_method` will override the first `new_method`, and the result of calling `new_method` will be `#do something else`.

Comment: I guess "cannot do this" was used liberally. Technically you can do all sorts of funky things, except you get thrown an error. Regardless, yes i agree you "can" do it, I figured it was about getting the point across that you shouldn't be naming to methods with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

## With two more methods

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= find_user_by_id || find_user_by_token
end

private

def find_user_by_id
  User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

def find_user_by_token
  User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
end
```

## With boolean logic

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= (session[:user_id]    && User.find(session[:user_id])) ||
                    (cookies[:auth_token] && User.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]))
end
```